# Is it possible to wrap multiple print commands that contain, strings, variables, and integers, to a variable that can later be written to a file

Tags: python, for-loop

```
 #attempt to print the contents individually-FAILED
 cut=(
 ('total genes',Signature_1, str(len(NameA))),
 ('up genes',Signature_1, str(len(upA))))
 for i in cut:
     print(i)

 #actual output=('total genes', 'V.txt', '3725')
 #desired output=total genes V.txt 3725
 
 #example of multiple print commands I would like to execute and write to a file
 print('down genes',Signature_1,len(downA)),
 print('total genes',Signature_2, len(NameB)),
 print('up genes',Signature_2,len(upB)),
```

Attempting to combine multiple print statements under a single variable and execute a for loop to print each line within that variable. Ultimately, I am doing this in order to write the output to a .txt file. sys.stdout does perform desired function, but the block acts like a recursive loop and never terminates, looking for alternatives. So far my only ideas are to group each text under one variable and execute a for loop (this has failed). My second approach was to group the multiple print methods under a variable and execute each from the variable level (also failed & and not sure if possible). Any alternatives or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `list comprehension` for joining the nested tuples in `cut` and `join` again the multiple strings generated by the first `join` to break them into separate lines, like shown below:

```
cut=(
 ('total genes',Signature_1, str(len(NameA))),
 ('up genes',Signature_1, str(len(upA))))

lines = '\n'.join([' '.join(i) for i in cut])
```

Would this work for you?